# SAS array unable to process long list of variables

Tags: arrays, sas

I am trying to log, square, cubic and log-odds transform my input data to provide an exhaustive overview of the best performing transformation in univariate regression

I have tried the following code on a dataset with 1,000 variables - It returns an error / runs out of memory or simply cannot execute. Are there any limitations with transforming variables en-masse in this way using arrays?

```
/*Create a table for reference*/
DATA input_data;
    ARRAY var_[*] var_1-var_1000;

    DO i = 1 to 1000;
        DO i = 1 to 1000;
            var_(i)= i*j;
            output;
        END;
    END;
RUN;

/*Log, square, cubic, logit transform all variables*/
DATA input_transform;
    SET input_data;
    ARRAY var[*]    var_1-var_1000;
    ARRAY log[*]    log_1-log_1000;
    ARRAY logit[*]  logit_1-logit_1000;
    ARRAY sq[*]     sq_1-sq_1000;
    ARRAY cubic[*]  cubic_1-cubic_1000;

    DO i = 1 to 1000;
        log(i)      = log(var(i));
        logit(i)    = log((var(i))/(1-var(i)));
        sq(i)       = var(i)**2;
        cubic(i)    = var(i)**3;
    END;
RUN;
```

A new dataset with 5000 variables each with the respective transformation

Comment: Show the ERRORs reported in the log window.  Add some details about the machine: operating system and version, RAM and DISK available, SAS version, log messages from `proc options group=( memory ) restrict;run;`

Comment: I will add this Monday morning when I have access to SAS again

Comment: Perhaps you are just filling the disk with divide by zero, numeric overflow and other error messages being written to the SAS log?

Comment: @78282219 your code errors out, perhaps fix the errors first and then include the log if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `I` as the index variable for both or your two nested do loops. That is probably messing them up.

Also your first data step is writing 1,000,000 observations of 1,002 variables with only the lower left triangle of the "array" filled in.  Do you really want the `OUTPUT` statement inside the loop?

Comment: That would be 1M rows if the inner `I` loop first corrected to `J`

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing this out - I can't access SAS right now so I created some hypothetical code to make a case. The focus of this question is why my SAS fails when running the transformation over large arrays

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically there are no issues with this, as long as your code is correct. Here's an example and the log.

```
option notes;
%let size=1000;

/*Create a table for reference*/
DATA input_data;
    ARRAY var_[*] var_1-var_&size.;

    DO i = 1 to &size.;
        DO j = 1 to &size.;
            var_(j)= i*j;
        END;
        output;
    END;
RUN;

/*Log, square, cubic, logit transform all variables*/
DATA input_transform;
    SET input_data;
    ARRAY _var[*]    var_1-var_&size.;
    ARRAY _log[*]    log_1-log_&size.;
    ARRAY _logit[*]  logit_1-logit_&size.;
    ARRAY _sq[*]     sq_1-sq_&size.;
    ARRAY _cubic[*]  cubic_1-cubic_&size.;

    DO i = 1 to &size.;
        _log(i)      = log(_var(i));
         _logit(i)    = sqrt(_var(i));
        _sq(i)       = _var(i)**2;
        _cubic(i)    = _var(i)**3;
    END;
RUN;
```

and the log:

```
1576      option notes;
1577      %let size=1000;
1578
1579      /*Create a table for reference*/
1580      DATA input_data;
1581          ARRAY var_[*] var_1-var_&size.;
1582
1583          DO i = 1 to &size.;
1584              DO j = 1 to &size.;
1585                  var_(j)= i*j;
1586              END;
1587              output;
1588          END;
1589      RUN;

NOTE: The data set WORK.INPUT_DATA has 1000 observations and 1002
      variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds


1590
1591      /*Log, square, cubic, logit transform all variables*/
1592      DATA input_transform;
1593          SET input_data;
1594          ARRAY _var[*]    var_1-var_&size.;
1595          ARRAY _log[*]    log_1-log_&size.;
1596          ARRAY _logit[*]  logit_1-logit_&size.;
1597          ARRAY _sq[*]     sq_1-sq_&size.;
1598          ARRAY _cubic[*]  cubic_1-cubic_&size.;
1599
1600          DO i = 1 to &size.;
1601              _log(i)      = log(_var(i));
1602               _logit(i)    = sqrt(_var(i));
1603              _sq(i)       = _var(i)**2;
1604              _cubic(i)    = _var(i)**3;
1605          END;
1606      RUN;

NOTE: There were 1000 observations read from the data set
      WORK.INPUT_DATA.
NOTE: The data set WORK.INPUT_TRANSFORM has 1000 observations and 5002
      variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.12 seconds
      cpu time            0.10 seconds
```

Comment: Hi Reeza, I'll run this again on Monday when I have access and I will share the issue.